# How to do initialization of vector for an algorithm in MATLAB?

Tags: optimization, matrices, signal-processing

```
L=4;  N=4;  N_l=2;  P=10;

w = ones(L,1);
beta = ones(L,1);
%p = zeros(L,1);
H = sqrt(.5)*(randn(N_l,N)+1i*(randn(N_l,N)));
u_l = sqrt(.5)*(randn(N,1)+1i*(randn(N,1)));
u_i = sqrt(.5)*(randn(N,1)+1i*(randn(N,1)));
v_l = sqrt(.5)*(randn(N_l,1)+1i*(randn(N_l,1)));
u_l = u_l./norm(u_l,2);
v_l = v_l./norm(v_l,2);
u_i = u_i./norm(u_i,2);
for k = 1:L
    p(k,:)=P/L;
    w'*p(k)<=P
```

I have to generate random vectors for p^(0), u_l and v_l for l=1...L. Now I am confused about how to generate these vectors as l=1..L is the number of users, for example, I have L=2 then the generation of vectors should like p^(1) p^(2) for u_1 u_2 v_1 v_2 and after that, I have performed steps 1 and 2 respectively, for each l. Kindly guide me I am very confused.[image]

Comment: Matlab-specific questions are off-topic here. Does your question still make sense in a language-agnostic setting?

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com